# how can i get a next form/page while each submitting form?

Tags: django, forms

i am working with a django quiz application where one question per page. when i will answer one question selecting a radio button and click submit button how can i get the next question in the next page as well as the answer will submitted to database. If anyone help me it would be an outstanding solution for me. please
I wrote a view to get the question and render the answer in the radio link . but when i submit the answer how can i map the url to get dynamically new question each. thank you so much.
I need a simplest solution please ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpResponseRedirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) to point from the currently submitted page to the next.
For example (for simplicity, I assume you have a question model that points to the next question for each question):

```
def view_question(request,id):
    q = Question.objects.get(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           # this takes care of saving the answer
           a = Answer.objects.create(user=request.user, question=q, a = form.cleaned_data['answer'])
           # this takes care of moving on to the next question
           if q.next_question != None:
               return HttpResponseRedirect(q.next_question.get_absolute_url())
           # no next question, finished quiz
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/done-quiz/')
    else:
       form = QuestoinForm()

    return render_to_response('quiz.html', {'form': form, 'question':q})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving this valuable answer.